# I cannot get solidity installed with homebrew on macOS Sierra. Installation hangs at boost

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew, ethereum, solidity

I have tried to install solidity on my Mac with

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install solidity

brew linkapps solidity
```

as suggested at [solidity#binary-packages](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html#binary-packages). But when I try to `brew install solidity` the installation process gets stuck right here when installing boost:

```
    bash-3.2$ brew install solidity
==> Installing solidity from ethereum/ethereum
==> Installing dependencies for ethereum/ethereum/solidity: boost, cryptopp, gmp
==> Installing ethereum/ethereum/solidity dependency: boost
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.64.0/source/boost_1_64_0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Users/Me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-1.64.0.tar.bz2
==> Downloading https://github.com/boostorg/mpi/commit/f5bdcc1.patch
Already downloaded: /Users/Me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost--patch-c7af75a83fef90fdb9858bc988d64ca569ae8d940396b9bc60a57d63fca2587b.patch
==> Downloading https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/commit/1d86261.diff
Already downloaded: /Users/Me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost--patch-155f603a00975a1702808be072c1420964feac8323de39c111a9d3a363a4ed9a.diff
==> Patching
==> Applying f5bdcc1.patch
patching file boost/mpi/detail/mpi_datatype_primitive.hpp
patching file boost/mpi/detail/packed_iprimitive.hpp
patching file boost/mpi/detail/packed_oprimitive.hpp
Hunk #2 succeeded at 97 (offset -5 lines).
==> Applying 1d86261.diff
patching file boost/serialization/array.hpp
==> ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.64.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.64.0_1/lib --without-icu --without-libraries=python,mp
==> ./b2 headers
==> ./b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.64.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.64.0_1/lib -d2 -j4 --layout=tagged --user-config=user-config.jam
```

I did find this [brew hanging thread](https://superuser.com/questions/642113/brew-hanging-seemingly-frozen-when-installing-boost-for-nearly-an-hour) and tried to fix everything `brew doctor` gave me and I have the latest command line tools installed. I could not get it to work yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JK! Wow. I guess one of the manny things I tried must have worked. Now it still takes a very very long time but eventually it came to:

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.64.0_1: 12,630 files, 404.4MB, built in 17 minutes 38 seconds
```

17minutes. Wow.

Comment: Just run brew with `--verbose` to get compilation output.

Comment: `  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.64.0_1: 12,630 files, 404.4MB, built in 58 minutes 26 seconds` for me. Boy that took a long time.

Comment: The command started the Exhaust fans of the machine. Wondered if everything is fine.